# Plot[] fails to show all results of Solve[]

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm interested in the intersection points of two functions: $y=r+x$, where $r$ is the constant, and $y=ln(1+x)$. The following code plots the two intersection points for different (negative values) of $r$ correctly and as expected:

```
Manipulate[
pts = Quiet[Solve[y == r + x && y == Log[1 + x], {x, y}]];
Graphics[Point[{x, y} /. pts], PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, {-3, 2}}, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, Frame -> True],
{r, -2, 0}]
```

[image]

However, if I try to plot data corresponding only to $x$ coordinate (or $y$) as a function of constant $r$ using a similar code (logic) I get only one intersection point (for $r<0$). The code in question is the following:

```
xr[r_] := Quiet[Solve[y == r + x && y == Log[1 + x], {x, y}]][[1,1](*Part: flattening and selecting x only*)
Plot[Evaluate[x /. xr[r]], {r, -2, 0}, FrameLabel -> {r, x}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

Why isn't Plot[] able to access both intersection points (it did it above)? It shows only the negative $x$ values (positive branch is omitted).

[image]

P.S. Solve is also unable to produce the complete result by solving $r+x-ln(1+x)=0$ for $x$, that's the reason why I'm solving the system of two equations rather than this single equation.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) uses inverse functions, not all solutions get returned. You could use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) instead:

```
Reduce[r+x == Log[1+x], x, Reals]
```

> Reduce::useq: The answer found by Reduce contains unsolved equation(s) {0==-1+r-Log[-ProductLog[-1,Times[<<2>>]]]-ProductLog[-1,-E^Plus[<<2>>]],0==-1+r-Log[-ProductLog[Times[<<2>>]]]-ProductLog[-E^Plus[<<2>>]]}. A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions.
>
> (r == 0 && 
>      x == 0) || (0 == -1 + r - Log[-ProductLog[-1, -E^(-1 + r)]] - 
>        ProductLog[-1, -E^(-1 + r)] && r <= 0 && 
>      x == -1 - ProductLog[-1, -E^(-1 + r)]) || (0 == -1 + r - 
>        Log[-ProductLog[-E^(-1 + r)]] - ProductLog[-E^(-1 + r)] && r <= 0 && 
>      x == -1 - ProductLog[-E^(-1 + r)])

The output is messy and generates messages, but the key is the two-arg form of ProductLog. So, a function that returns both roots is:

```
f[r_] := -1 - ProductLog[{0, -1}, -Exp[-1 + r]]
```

Example:

```
f[-.89]
```

> {-0.818943, 1.98289}

Comment: Thank you Carl! Reduce[] did indeed generate the correct results. If it's not a bother, I still don't understand one thing, Solve[] seemed to generate both real roots inside the Manipulate[] function in my first code snippet. Why can't it do it in the second code example? '{x, y} /. pts' replacement seems to somehow help the situation in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

If r is greater than zero the two lines do not cross and the solutions are imaginary.

We can make a little module to solve for x and y given r

```
xy[r_] := 
 Module[{}, 
  Transpose[{x, y}] /. 
   Quiet[Solve[y == r + x && y == Log[1 + x], {x, y}, Reals]]]
```

To illustrate this, we can plot the two lines and the  real solutions as we adjust R

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[{r + x, Log[1 + x]}, {x, -10, 10}],
  ListPlot[xy[r], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
  ], {{r, -2}, -10, 10}]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get solutions without error messages. Since you regard real solutions, apply `Exp` to both sides of eqn und use `Method->Reduce`.

```
eqn = r + x == Log[1 + x];

xsol[r_] = x /. Solve[Map[Exp, eqn, 1], x, Reals, Method -> Reduce]

(*   {ConditionalExpression[-1 - ProductLog[-E^(-1 + r)], r <= 0], 
      ConditionalExpression[-1 - ProductLog[-1, -E^(-1 + r)], r <= 0]}   *)

xsol[-.89]
(*   {-0.818943, 1.98289}   *)

Plot[xsol[r], {r, -10, 0}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[Thread[{xsol[r], r}], {r, -10, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> Full]
```